# XJC "Is not part of this compilation" issue

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xjc

I'm using the Maven JAXB2 Plugin to generate Java classes from my XSDs.

For that, I use multiple executions as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xsd1</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-b</argument>
                    <argument>${basedir}/src/main/xjb/xsd1.xjb</argument>
                </arguments>
                <sources>
                    <source>${basedir}/src/main/xsd/xsd1.xsd</source>
                </sources>  
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>xsd2</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-b</argument>
                    <argument>${basedir}/src/main/xjb/xsd2.xjb</argument>
                </arguments>
                <sources>
                    <source>${basedir}/src/main/xsd/xsd2.XSD</source>
                </sources>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My XJBs:

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    schemaLocation="../xsd/xsd1.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.example.xsd1" />
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
    <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='Name']/xsd:complexType">
        <jxb:class name="NameXsd1" />
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>

<jxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    schemaLocation="../xsd/xsd2.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.example.xsd2" />
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
    <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='Name']/xsd:complexType">
        <jxb:class name="NameXsd2" />
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

When I do a `mvn clean install` I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] file:/D:/Dev/myproject/src/main/xjb/xsd1.xjb [3,92] 
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/D:/Dev/myproject/src/main/xjb/xsd1.xjb; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 92; "file:/D:/Dev/myproject/src/main/xsd/xsd1.xsd" is not part of this compilation. Is it a mistake for "file:/D:/Dev/myproject/src/main/xsd/xsd2.xsd" ?
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:624)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:618)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:261)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:146)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:107)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.transform(DOMForest.java:439)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.buildDOMForest(ModelLoader.java:345)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:377)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:174)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:354)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.javageneration.AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.performExecution(AbstractJavaGeneratorMojo.java:402)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractJaxbMojo.execute(AbstractJaxbMojo.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jaxb2-maven-plugin` considers both of your XJB files.

You'll have to configure
`xjbExcludeFilters` or `xjbSources` to include just one file:

```
<xjbSources>
    <xjbSource>src/main/xjb/xsd1.xjb</xjbSource>
</xjbSources>
```

Comment: YES!, Finally this was the fix. Just insert this in the second configuration, and it won't complain again. Thanks @lexicore

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and figured out that if I put the xjb file in the xsd directory that my issue also resolved.  My configuration was using cxf-xjc-util in maven.  Thought I'd post this some where since I haven't seen this version of an answer to the question.